# NAS D-Link DNS320 - set a password protected directory

Tags: security, nas

I set up D-Link DNS-320 NAS in my LAN environment (at this moment every computer in the LAN rans Windows XP or Windows 7, but one day this could change). It does the job but the question is: Is there a way to password protect a directory?

For instance, given a directory on my NAS (i.e: *dir A* and *dir B*) I would like that if someone tries to open it a user/password will be required to continue. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

yes
but it depends on your NAS configurations
if you bought NAS (device not in windows server) i mean physically,then go to default web interface and then set password for each users group
in Dlink it can be done easily

Comment: please tell me your device model,for more help ;)

Comment: DNS320. I wrote in the title :)

Comment: oh yep :).go to your D-link web interface and advance section and then create new user and change permissions ;)

Comment: read page 27- 31 of [this](http://www.dlink.com/ca/en/support/product/-/media/Consumer_Products/DNS/DNS%20320/Manual/DNS-320_Manual_US.pdf) for more details ;)